# WordPress rewrite on Windows (with IIS and ASP.NET site)

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, windows, iis, url-rewriting

I started installing (through the Web Installer Platform) a WordPress blog on my Windows 2012 Server.
On the same server I’m already running a ASP.NET MVC 4.5 website. This website has a localization module built in, that takes the culture-code of the visitor (for example ‘en’) and places this in the URLs.
By the way: I need the WordPress blog to run in a subfolder, namely: /blog

So, to summarize:
https://example.com/en returns successfully my ASP.NET website
https://example.com/en/blog should return my WordPress blog.

Now, when I proceed configuring the WordPress site by opening https://example.com/en/blog/wp-admin/install.php, it shows me the fields for entering the site title, username + password and email. This is done on install.php?step=1.

When clicking ‘install wordpress’ it should take me to install.php?step=2. But instead of taking me to https://example.com/en/blog/wp-admin/install.php?step2, it takes me to https://example.com/en/install.php?step=2. It just removes the /blog/wp-admin/ part from the URL. This results in a 404 since this page obviously doesn’t exist.

I have not set up any rule in the web.config or IIS. Should I do this to fix this problem?

Is there anyone who can help me out there?

Comment: sounds like a routing issue... maybe check this:  https://www.gmass.co/blog/wordpress-pages-and-asp-net-mvc-same-iis-folder/

Comment: Yeah, I indeed already had a look at this blog. 
However, when I include both in the web.config on the root AND in the web.config in the /blog folder the following rule, it gives me 500 error on mydomain.com/blog

    <rule name="Rewrite Blog" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^blog$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
    </rule>

Comment: In that link the WordPress site is at the root and ASP.NET is in a subfolder.  If you redirect "blog" to index, it's going back to the root and trying to find a php page.  I would consider a different domain for each.  Seems like a mess to mix the two routing schemes.

Comment: Hi Have you tried to rewrite the url en/install.php?step=2 back to en/blog/wp-admin/install.php?step=2 with URL rewrite?

Comment: @JokiesDing yes, but that doesn't help because it will reload the page with the inital fields again (step=... is a function within the install.php). 
And apart from that: the problem isn't only with the install.php page. The general issue (wrong rewritten urls) will keep happening, also on other pages, once the blog installation has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by adding "blog" in the global.asax.cs in the ExclusionFilter as follows:

i18n.UrlLocalizer.QuickUrlExclusionFilter = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?:sitemap.xml|.css|.jpg|.png|.svg|.woff|.woff2|.eot|.js|.html|.json)$|(?:blog)");